# In partial differential equation I have to discuss about exsitance of F in equation in the form of h(t)=F(g(t)), h and g.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations

In partial differential equation, I have to discuss the existence of $F$ in the equation $h(t)=F(g(t))$, $h$ and $g$ are known.

For example $\sin t+t=F(5+\cos t)$.

I think using implicit function theorem I can say the equation has a unique solution but I do not know how to set it up

Comment: If I were to set a bounty, I would at least check my spelling & format the question appropriately. Also, try to read what you wrote out loud. (: $$$$ 'In the partial differential equation... in the equation...'

Answer (score 0):

Actually such $F$ doesn't necessarily always exist. Let's have:

$h:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$

$h(t)=t$

$g:\Bbb{R}\to[-1,1]$

$g(t)=\sin(t)$

Then $F$ would have to satisfy $\forall_{t\in\Bbb{R}}\space h(t)=F(g(t))=F(\sin t)$.

That, in turn, would imply these equalities:

$0=h(0)=F(\sin0)=F(\sin\pi)=h(\pi)=\pi$.

An obvious contradiction.

So the existence of such F actually depends on our choice of $h,g$, and their respective domains.

Comment: You can use \to instead of \rightarrow, but the output is the same.

Comment: Can yoyu please explain when it is true.

Comment: Well such $F$ would have to be a surjection from %g[D]$ on $h[D]$ where $D$ is your domain of $g$ and $h$. So $F$ exists if and only if $|g[D]|\geq|h[D]|$.